# Passport-Facebook req.user is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am attempting to use the passport-facebook Passport strategy for user authentication.  When I try to access `req.user._id`, I get error

```
`TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined.`
```

I've looked through other answers related to this, which all seem to revolve around session middlewares but everything seems to be in order. I have a feeling it may have something to do with the fact that I'm running a react-webpack-dev server on port 3000 which proxies backend requests to the express app at port 3001, but I'm not really sure.

routes.js:

```
 var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

    console.log("LOGGED IN")
    return next()
  }
  console.log("NOT LOGGED IN")
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/facebook')
}

  // get logged in users' feed array, and return threads 
  router.get('/api/feed', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
      console.log("LOGGED IN")
    User.findOne({'_id': req.user._id }, function (err, user) {
      Thread.find({
        '_id': { $in: user.feed }
      }).sort('-date').exec(function (err, threads) {
          console.log(threads)
          res.json(threads)
      })
    })
  })

  router.get('/api/auth/facebook', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { authType: 'rerequest' }),
    router.get('/api/auth/facebook/callback',
      passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000',
        failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/signup',
        session: true
      }), function (req, res) {
        req.session.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        })
      })
    )
```

server.js:

```
var settings = require('./config')

// Express server, which handles requests on port 3001
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var passport = require('passport')
var session = require('express-session')
var app = express()

app.set('port', settings.expressPort)

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(session({secret: 'secret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
var initPassport = require('./passport/init')
initPassport(passport)

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb', function (err, db) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Connected to Database. . .')
  } else {
    console.log(err)
  }
})

require('./models/Thread')
require('./models/Comment')
require('./models/User')

var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport)
app.use('/', routes)


app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server started at http://localhost:' + settings.expressPort + '/')
})

var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

// Hot-reloading dev-server
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  // Proxy backend requests to Express server
  proxy: {
    "/api/*": "http://localhost:" + settings.expressPort
  }
}).listen(settings.webpackServerPort, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Webpack dev react server listening at http://localhost:' + settings.webpackServerPort +  '/');
});
```

passport/facebook.js:

```
var FaceBookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var User = mongoose.model('User')
var config = require('../config')

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user)
    })
  })

  passport.use(new FaceBookStrategy({
    clientID:          config.auth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret:      config.auth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL:       config.auth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
    scope:             ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends'],
    profileFields:     ['id', 'displayName', 'email', 'friends']
  },

  // facebook sends back token and profile
  function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    // async
    process.nextTick(function () {
      User.findOne({ 'facebook.id': profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        if (err)
          return done(err);
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user)
        } else {
          var newUser = new User()
          newUser.facebook.id = profile.id
          newUser.facebook.token = token
          newUser.facebook.name = profile.displayName
          if (profile.emails) {
            newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value
          }
          newUser.facebook.friends = profile._json.friends.data 
          newUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
              throw err
            return done(null, newUser)
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }
  ))
}
```

Accessing `/api/auth/facebook`seems to work normally. If I log out of facebook and try to access /api/feed, it redirects me to facebook login page, then after logging in, redirects me to my feed page. However, `req.user` is still undefined.

EDIT: I am now seeing the following error in chrome console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?auth_type=rerequest&response_type=cod…back&scope=public_profile%2Cemail%2Cuser_friends&client_id=285831851754236. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Because you are not using parentheses.  

`if (req.isAuthenticated())
    console.log("LOGGED IN")
    return next()` should be

`if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("LOGGED IN")
    return next()
}`

Comment: Ah, dumb mistake. Now I am getting NOT LOGGED IN. Still don't know why passport isn't authenticating. Edited question

Comment: Fixed your routes definitions here : https://jsfiddle.net/3j59fuqz/1/

Comment: Actually this works now after setting my ajax datatype from 'json' to 'jsonp', although I'm getting a new error undefined "parsererror" "Error:jQuery22204349174060433989_1464373063513 was not called". If you want to submit an answer I'll mark this thread as answered